# Detecting Runtime Errors in Arcpy Loops

Tags: python, arcpy, arcmap

I am looping over a feature in Arcpy and doing several geoProcessing tasks on each feature/iteration.

The loop runs pretty well but crashes on some of the features. I dont really know why but its probably because of some geometry error or something weird.

[image]

I can see what files have been output along the way so I can simply restart the loop and bypass the bad feature.

If I could somehow detect a runtime error like above, I could restart the loop and bypass the bad features. Is there any way to fire a function on a Runtime Error event?

Comment: Are you accessing data off a server?  I am wondering if the failure is due to a `.loc` file.

Comment: No - All the data is local

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a `try/except` statement.  For example:

```
for fc in fclist:
    try:
        yourFunction(fc)
    except:
        # Do something, possibly fix geometry
        print there was a problem with %s...moving on" % fc
        continue
```

You can also get more specific and handle only ExecuteErrors using `except arcpy.ExecuteError:`:

More details:

[Error handling with Python](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z0000000q000000)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I just found the thread below so maybe it should be linked or my question should be deleted? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33384/how-to-bypass-errors-in-arcpy-for-while-loop